# Proofs regarding Ceilings and Floors

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I understand the concept of what ceilings and floors when using numbers; however, when it comes to proofs I am so lost, I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on some useful links that could help me do proofs with ceilings and floors.

I understand the general definition; however I don't know how to take it from there.

for example: prove
$ n =⌊n/3⌋+ ⌈n/3⌉ +⌈n-1/3⌉ $

I know that by definition that x <= ⌊n/3⌋

Comment: The third term should probably be $\lceil \frac{n-1}3\rceil$ rather that $\lceil n-\frac13\rceil$...

Comment: Separate it into cases : $n=3k,3k+1,3k+2$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Mathlove's hint is the solution.

But I'm not Mathlove so I did it the hard way.  But this illustrates how I thought about it and came to a conclusion.

Well, let $\frac n 3 = m + a$ where m is an integer and $0<= a < 1$.

As n is an integer, $a = 0$ and $n = 3m$ or $a = 1/3$ and $n = 3m + 1$ or $a = 2/3$ and $n = 3m + 2$.

Then $⌊n/3⌋ = m$.

$⌈n/3⌉ = m + 1$ if a > 0 and $⌈n/3⌉ = m$ if a = 0.

$⌈(n−1)/3⌉ = ⌈n/3 −1/3⌉ =$... well $(n-1)/3 = m + a - 1/3$.  So $⌈(n−1)/3⌉  = n$ if a = 0 or a = 1/3. $⌈(n−1)/3⌉ =  n + 1$ if a = 2/3

So divide it into cases.

Case 1: $a = 0$.  ⌊n/3⌋+⌈n/3⌉+⌈(n−1)/3⌉ = m + m + m = 3m = 3m  = n.

Case 2: $a = 1/3$.   ⌊n/3⌋+⌈n/3⌉+⌈(n−1)/3⌉ = m + (m + 1) + m = 3m + 1 = n.

Case 3: $a = 2/3$   ⌊n/3⌋+⌈n/3⌉+⌈(n−1)/3⌉ = m + (m + 1) + (m + 1) = 3m + 2 = n.